# How do I chain multiple orElse in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my method

```
private Employee getEmployee(String employeeId) {
    Employee employee = null;
    if (employeeId != null && !employeeId.isEmpty()) {
        employee = employeeService.find(employeeId)
            .orElse(employeeService.findEmployeeByName(employeeId));
    }
    return employee;
}
```

Here, I am trying to add another orElse so that if both fail to return anything, use a new service like so with a 'Y' at the end.

```
private Employee getEmployee(String employeeId) {
    Employee employee = null;
    if (employeeId != null && !employeeId.isEmpty()) {
        employee = employeeService.find(employeeId)
            .orElse(employeeService.findEmployeeBySocialId(employeeId))
            .orElse(employeeService.findEmployeeBySocialId(employeeId + 'Y'));
    }
    return employee;
}
```

But I get an error saying cannot resolve method 'orElse'. What are some other ways to accomplish this? Also, the "find" service method returns optional where as the "findEmployeeBySocialId" method returns Employee object.

Comment: If `findEmployeeBySocialId` always returns a valid employee, in what cases do you expect the second `orElse` to be entered?

Comment: So `findEmployeeBySocialId` can return null? How about changing it to return an `Optional` instead? Then you can use `or`.

Answer (score 7):

The `orElse` method returns an actual (non-optional) object, so you can't chain it. You're looking for `or`:

```
    employee = employeeService.find(employeeId)
        .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findEmployeeBySocialId(employeeId)))
        .or(() -> Optional.ofNullable(employeeService.findEmployeeBySocialId(employeeId + 'Y')));

    return employee.orElse(null); // or make your method return an Optional
```

The `or` method takes a `Supplier` because it should only be called if the previous `Optional` was empty.

It would be better if `findEmployeeBySocialId` returned an `Optional`; then you won't need to wrap it with `Optional.ofNullable`.